# how do I make another button appear if I pressed one button in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a game where if I press a button it can spawn another button in another area so you can click and keep doing that, every time you press the button you should get a point. I don't know how to spawn another button when I pressed one button.

// this is the code

var monkeyPosition : Int = 1

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.25, alpha: 1.0)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.25, alpha: 1.0)
    view.addSubview(makeButtonSpawn())
    view.addSubview(makeButtonSpawn2())

}



@IBAction func monkeyPlayer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 1 && (monkeyPosition == 1) {
        makeButtonSpawn2().isHidden = false

    }


}



func makeButtonSpawn() -> UIButton {

    let monkey = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
    //Set a frame for the button. Ignored in AutoLayout/ Stack Views
    monkey.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 90, height: 90)
    monkey.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    makeButtonSpawn().isHidden = true
    return monkey
}

func makeButtonSpawn2() -> UIButton {
    let monkey = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
    //Set a frame for the button. Ignored in AutoLayout/ Stack Views
    monkey.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 90, height: 90)
    monkey.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
 makeButtonSpawn2().isHidden = true
    return monkey

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create instance variables for your buttons, then you will be able to access them from places in your class. Also you can set its properties inside variable closure instead of declaring method

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button1: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 90, height: 90)
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        return button
    }()

    var button2: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 90, height: 90)
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.isHidden = true
        return button
    }()
}
```

Next, you need to add your buttons as subviews to main `view` and you need to add target for them

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.25, alpha: 1.0)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.25, alpha: 1.0)
    view.addSubview(button1)
    view.addSubview(button2)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1Pressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button2Pressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func button1Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

}

@objc func button2Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```

Finally, you can unhide second button when first button is pressed

```
@objc func button1Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if monkeyPosition == 1 {
        button2.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I have another question how can I make it so the button is not a color but an image that I have is the Assets.